# How to resize root partition on aws ec2 rhel7 ami?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, redhat, xfs

I created a t2.micro instance from rhel7 ami-f7f03d80 ami, with a 39gb gp2 xfs_ebs storage, and have a 6gb / xfs filesystem, and a 24gb of free space. I am trying to use `xfs_growfs -d /` for resizing a partition, and it says `data size unchanged, skipping`. when i'm specifying `-D 2572864` to xfs_growfs, it says `data size 2572864 too large, maximum is 1572864`. looks like i need to resize a partition first, and then resize a filesystem, but i can't do that on a mounted fs. I could pack fdisk and xfs_growfs to initrd, and boot from it, but it seems too hard) It seems like i missed something, and it could be done other way. Thanks.

Comment: check: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14930504/1251660

Comment: i cant do step 5: Detach current volume. It's root fs.

Comment: Why not? I have done this procedure a 100 times and it works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

It'll feel a little scary (take a snapshot first) but:

```
fdisk /dev/YOURDEVICE
```

delete your partition, create a new partition taking the whole disk, write changes, reboot.

You should see the whole drive after that.

Comment: I had to run `xfs_growfs /dev/sda1` afterwards so that `df -h` would update. This worked perfectly on my 1 partition root disk.

Answer (score 1):

I have incressed my root partion space by gdisk on RHEL 7

1) yum -y install gdisk

2) sudo gdisk /dev/xvda

Delete all the partions

3)

`Command (? for help): o
This option deletes all partitions and creates a new protective MBR.
Proceed? (Y/N): Y`

4) 
Use the n command to create a new partition entry for each partition on the device.

`Command (? for help): n
Partition number (1-128, default 1): 1
First sector (34-209715166, default = 2048) or {+-}size{KMGTP}:  2048
Last sector (2048-209715166, default = 209715166) or {+-}size{KMGTP}: 4095
Current type is 'Linux filesystem'
Hex code or GUID (L to show codes, Enter = 8300): EF02
Changed type of partition to 'BIOS boot partition'`

`Command (? for help): n
Partition number (2-128, default 2): 2
First sector (34-209715166, default = 4096) or {+-}size{KMGTP}: 4096
Last sector (4096-209715166, default = 209715166) or {+-}size{KMGTP}: 209715166
Current type is 'Linux filesystem'
Hex code or GUID (L to show codes, Enter = 8300): 0700
Changed type of partition to 'Microsoft basic data'`

5) Use the w command to write the changes to the device and exit.

`Expert command (? for help): w`

Final checks complete. About to write GPT data. THIS WILL OVERWRITE EXISTING
PARTITIONS!!

Do you want to proceed? (Y/N): Y
OK; writing new GUID partition table (GPT) to /dev/xvda.
The operation has completed successfully.

6) Reboot the system
7) After reboot you can see your /root partion size increassed

Comment: Thanks - the first guide that I've tried that didn't corrupt my partition table on AWS/RHEL.