# EC2 Storage attached at sda is /dev/xvde1 cannot resize

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, centos

I have cPanel & WHm installed on an EC2 instance.

The EC2 EBS volume is 100GB 
CentOS 6 x86_64 (2014_09_29) EBS pv-1-adc4348e-1dc3-41df-b833-e86ba57a33d6-ami-809020e8.2 (ami-bc8131d4)

This is what df -h shows:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvde1      7.8G  6.6G  834M  89% /
tmpfs           3.7G     0  3.7G   0% /dev/shm
/usr/tmpDSK     485M   11M  449M   3% /tmp
```

The EBS is mounted at `/dev/sda`

I am trying to increase the size of the `xvde1` to almost fill the 100GB

When I run `resize2fs /dev/xvde1` i get this:

```
root@vs1 [~]# resize2fs /dev/xvde1
resize2fs 1.41.12 (17-May-2010)
The filesystem is already 2096896 blocks long.  Nothing to do!
```

I have tried the solution stated here: [EC2 Can't resize volume after increasing size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11014584/ec2-cant-resize-volume-after-increasing-size)

But when i reboot the instance it gets stuck on `1/2 Status Checks`

I saw something that stated to start the partition on `16` and also to use the same start as it is in the original configuration. This did not work.

Here is some more information and other things that i have tried:

```
root@vs1 [~]# resize2fs /dev/xvde1
resize2fs 1.41.12 (17-May-2010)
The filesystem is already 2096896 blocks long.  Nothing to do!

root@vs1 [~]# resize2fs /dev/xvde
resize2fs 1.41.12 (17-May-2010)
resize2fs: Device or resource busy while trying to open /dev/xvde
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.
root@vs1 [~]# resize2fs /dev/xvde1
resize2fs 1.41.12 (17-May-2010)
The filesystem is already 2096896 blocks long.  Nothing to do!

root@vs1 [~]# resize2fs /dev/xvde1 +25G
resize2fs 1.41.12 (17-May-2010)
The containing partition (or device) is only 2096896 (4k) blocks.
You requested a new size of 6553600 blocks.

root@vs1 [~]# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvde1      7.8G  6.6G  834M  89% /
tmpfs           3.7G     0  3.7G   0% /dev/shm
/usr/tmpDSK     485M   11M  449M   3% /tmp
root@vs1 [~]# resize2fs /dev/xvde1 +15g
resize2fs 1.41.12 (17-May-2010)
The containing partition (or device) is only 2096896 (4k) blocks.
You requested a new size of 3932160 blocks.

root@vs1 [~]# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvde1      7.8G  6.6G  834M  89% /
tmpfs           3.7G     0  3.7G   0% /dev/shm
/usr/tmpDSK     485M   11M  449M   3% /tmp

root@vs1 [~]# resize2fs /dev/xvde1
resize2fs 1.41.12 (17-May-2010)
The filesystem is already 2096896 blocks long.  Nothing to do!

root@vs1 [~]# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/xvde: 107.4 GB, 107374182400 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 13054 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00098461

    Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/xvde1   *           1        1045     8387584   83  Linux
root@vs1 [~]# Write failed: Broken pipe
```

This is the last step in a complete build that has taken over 18 hours.

I may just be delirious. Any and all help will be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

The system log on the server shows this, not sure if it is any help:

```
Thread "main": pointer: 0x21e0003760, stack: 0x3740000
"main" "root=/dev/sda" "ro" "4" 
vbd 2048 is hd0
******************* BLKFRONT for device/vbd/2048 **********


backend at /local/domain/0/backend/vbd/60/2048
209715200 sectors of 512 bytes
**************************
[H[J

    GNU GRUB  version 0.97  (7864320K lower / 0K upper memory)



[m[4;2H+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+[5;2H|[5;76H|[6;2H|[6;76H|[7;2H|[7;76H|[8;2H|[8;76H|[9;2H|[9;76H|[10;2H|[10;76H|[11;2H|[11;76H|[12;2H|[12;76H|[13;2H|[13;76H|[14;2H|[14;76H|[15;2H|[15;76H|[16;2H|[16;76H|[17;2H+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+[m

    Use the ^ and v keys to select which entry is highlighted.

    Press enter to boot the selected OS, 'e' to edit the

    commands before booting, or 'c' for a command-line.[5;78H [m[7m[5;3H CentOS (2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64)                                          [5;75H[m[m[6;3H CentOS (2.6.32-431.29.2.el6.x86_64)                                     [6;75H[m[m[7;3H                                                                         [7;75H[m[m[8;3H                                                                         [8;75H[m[m[9;3H                                                                         [9;75H[m[m[10;3H                                                                         [10;75H[m[m[11;3H                                                                         [11;75H[m[m[12;3H                                                                         [12;75H[m[m[13;3H                                                                         [13;75H[m[m[14;3H                                                                         [14;75H[m[m[15;3H                                                                         [15;75H[m[m[16;3H                                                                         [16;75H[m[16;78H [5;75H[23;4H The highlighted entry will be booted automatically in 1 seconds.   [5;75H[H[J  Booting 'CentOS (2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64)'



root (hd0,0)

 Filesystem type is ext2fs, partition type 0x83

kernel /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64 ro root=LABEL=_ console=ttyS0,115200

 crashkernel=no SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 LANG=en_US.UTF-8 KEYTABLE=us

initrd /boot/initramfs-2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64.img



============= Init TPM Front ================
Tpmfront:Error Unable to read device/vtpm/0/backend-id during tpmfront initialization! error = ENOENT
Tpmfront:Info Shutting down tpmfront
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> This answer is dangerous, hasn't been verified since 2016, and has the potential to delete your partition if you're not aware of what's happening. Use with caution, and please reference @Dmitry's answer below as well.

To expand on JD's answer, here's exactly what to do:

`df -h` #print the name of your boot partition

`lsblk` #show info on all your block devices

You'll see from that output what the name of the disk is of your root partition. For example, you probably see something like this:

```
xvde                               202:64   0   32G  0 disk 
└─xvde1                            202:65   0   8G  0 part /
```

Our goal is to make `xvde1` use the whole available space from `xvde`.
Here's how to resize your partition:

`fdisk /dev/xvda` (the disk name, not your partition)
This enters into the `fdisk` utility.

1. `u` #Change the display to sectors
2. `p` #Print info
3. `d` #Delete the partition
4. `n` #New partition
5. `p` #Primary partition
6. `1` #Partition number
7. `2048` #First sector
8. Press Enter to accept the default
9. `p` #Print info
10. `a` #Toggle the bootable flag
11. `1` #Select partition 1
12. `w` #Write table to disk and exit

Now, reboot your instance:
`reboot`

After it comes back do:

`resize2fs /dev/xvde1` (the name of your partition, not the block device)

And finally verify the new disk size:
`df -h`

Comment: You are the most amazon  man on planet Earth!   For months, I've searched for a solution to this.  Thanks so much for the detail!

Comment: @Andrew -  why d #Delete the partition ?
be careful from this answer, it may destroy your disk.

Comment: @Andrew - I think you should add a warning or at least an explanation. I almost deleted my data. Why d #Delete the partition. Wouldn't it delete all the data in the partition?

Comment: Welp....tried the above, and now my instance is bricked. Fun times.

Comment: I would delete this, but I can't since it's the accepted answer.

Answer (score 49):

Before resizing the filesystem by "resize2fs" command you should first resize your partition:

let's list block devices attached to our box:

```
lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda    202:0    0  16G  0 disk
└─xvda1 202:1    0   8G  0 part /
```

As you can see /dev/xvda1 is only 8 GiB partition on a 16 GiB device and there are no other partitions on the volume.

---

step-1) We will use "growpart" to resize 8G partition up to 16G:

```
# install "cloud-guest-utils" if it is not installed already
apt install cloud-guest-utils

# resize partition
growpart /dev/xvda 1
```

Let's check the result (you can see /dev/xvda1 is now 16G):

```
lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda    202:0    0  16G  0 disk
└─xvda1 202:1    0  16G  0 part /
```

Lots of SO answers suggest to use fdisk with delete / recreate partitions, which is nasty, risky, error-prone process especially when we change boot drive.

---

step-2) resize file system to grow all the way to fully use new partition space

```
# Check before resizing ("Avail" shows 1.1G):
df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      7.8G  6.3G  1.1G  86% /

# resize filesystem
resize2fs /dev/xvda1

# Check after resizing ("Avail" now shows 8.7G!-):
df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1       16G  6.3G  8.7G  42% /
```

And by the way, there's no need to stop instance and detach EBS volume to resize it anymore! 13-Feb-2017 Amazon announced: "[Amazon EBS Update – New Elastic Volumes Change Everything](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-ebs-update-new-elastic-volumes-change-everything/)" See my other [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42791031/7022062) for details.

Update: Use sudo xfs_growfs /dev/xvda1 instead of resize2fs  when XFS filesystem

Comment: This answer should be the default one. Thanks!

Comment: This is the right answer since you extend without lose data. Thanks bro.

Comment: Having gone through a number of blogs I can say that this as of my comment is the most up-to-date and safest method.

Comment: Use `sudo xfs_growfs /dev/xvda1` instead of `resize2fs ` when XFS filesystem.

Comment: This is the safe way!!!

Answer (score 3):

After searching and searching with no answer here, i FINALLY came across the answer!

"fdisk, put it into 'units' mode by typing 'u' then 'p' to print the partition table as it is now and write down the starting sector of the existing partition. Then delete that partition and make a new one, with the same partition number and starting on exactly the same sector and ending at the end of the disk, make sure that partition is 'active' then save your changes and reboot. Once you reboot after that, you should be able to resize2fs the existing filesystem to take up all space. Backups are recommended and it's your data to lose!!"

Putting it into sectors via Units mode helped me select the proper start and end of the FS!!

Credit: https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=4783

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is answered already. But still, if someone is stuck with the problem and need a more detailed step by step explanation. You can check out the official Amazon docs. This has the steps to increase the size and specific commands if you are using the "ec2-user (amazon ami)" instance.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/recognize-expanded-volume-linux.html

also if you are using windows instance. You can visit

*"For information about extending a Windows file system, see Extending a Windows file system after resizing a volume in the Amazon EC2 User Guide for Windows Instances."*

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/recognize-expanded-volume-windows.html

Answer (score 0):

None of the above answers helped me. Here is something to consider for centos.
I wanted to extend my root volume from 8GB to 16GB

```
[root@ip-10-0-0-218 ~]# cat /etc/centos-release
CentOS Linux release 8.2.2004 (Core)
```

Determine the current state

```
[root@ip-10-0-0-218 ~]# lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
nvme0n1     259:0    0   60G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0  600M  0 part /boot/efi
└─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0  7.8G  0 part /
```

First attempt to increase space (failed)

```
[root@ip-10-0-0-218 /]# xfs_growfs -d /dev/nvme0n1p2
meta-data=/dev/nvme0n1p2         isize=512    agcount=4, agsize=508800 blks
         =                       sectsz=512   attr=2, projid32bit=1
         =                       crc=1        finobt=1, sparse=1, rmapbt=0
         =                       reflink=1
data     =                       bsize=4096   blocks=2035200, imaxpct=25
         =                       sunit=0      swidth=0 blks
naming   =version 2              bsize=4096   ascii-ci=0, ftype=1
log      =internal log           bsize=4096   blocks=2560, version=2
         =                       sectsz=512   sunit=0 blks, lazy-count=1
realtime =none                   extsz=4096   blocks=0, rtextents=0
data size unchanged, skipping
```

Use Parted

```
[root@ip-10-0-0-218 ~]# parted
GNU Parted 3.2
Using /dev/nvme0n1
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) resizepart 2 +20GiB                                              
Warning: Partition /dev/nvme0n1p2 is being used. Are you sure you want to continue?
Yes/No? Yes                                                               
End?  [8966MB]? 16966MB 
quit
```

Now extend the size (success)

```
[root@ip-10-0-0-218 ~]# xfs_growfs /dev/nvme0n1p2
meta-data=/dev/nvme0n1p2         isize=512    agcount=4, agsize=508800 blks
         =                       sectsz=512   attr=2, projid32bit=1
         =                       crc=1        finobt=1, sparse=1, rmapbt=0
         =                       reflink=1
data     =                       bsize=4096   blocks=2035200, imaxpct=25
         =                       sunit=0      swidth=0 blks
naming   =version 2              bsize=4096   ascii-ci=0, ftype=1
log      =internal log           bsize=4096   blocks=2560, version=2
         =                       sectsz=512   sunit=0 blks, lazy-count=1
realtime =none                   extsz=4096   blocks=0, rtextents=0
data blocks changed from 2035200 to 3988233
```

Verify

```
[root@ip-10-0-0-218 ~]# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs        1.7G     0  1.7G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.7G     0  1.7G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           1.7G   22M  1.7G   2% /run
tmpfs           1.7G     0  1.7G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/nvme0n1p2   16G  7.1G  8.2G  47% /
/dev/nvme0n1p1  599M  6.4M  593M   2% /boot/efi
tmpfs           345M     0  345M   0% /run/user/1000
```

Answer (score -2):

```
1. Confirm the kernel.
~]# uname -r

  2.6.32-431.29.2.el6.x86_64

2. Confirm the initial allocated size

  ]# df -h
Filesystem Size Used Avail Use% Mounted on

 /dev/xvda1 7.9G 797M 6.7G 11% /

 tmpfs 498M 0 498M 0% /dev/shm


 # lsblk
NAME MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda 202:0 0 **15G 0 disk**
└─xvda1 202:1 0 **8G 0 part /**

3. Install EPEL6 Repo
~]# wget http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
~]# rpm -ivh epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm

3. Install the dracut & cloud-utils growpart modules-growroot
~]# yum install -y dracut-modules-growroot cloud-utils-growpart

4. The initrd needs to be rebuilt after installing the dracut-modules-growroot.
Create a backup copy of the current initramfs:
~]# cp -p /boot/initramfs-$(uname -r).img /boot/initramfs-$(uname -r).img.bak

(ii)Create the initramfs for the current kernel:
~]# dracut -f

 4. Result after reboot
~]# reboot

~]# lsblk
NAME MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda 202:0 0 **15G 0 disk**
└─xvda1 202:1 0 **15G 0 part /**

~]# resize2fs /dev/xvda1
resize2fs 1.41.12 (17-May-2010)
Filesystem at /dev/xvda1 is mounted on /; on-line resizing required
old desc_blocks = 1, new_desc_blocks = 1
Performing an on-line resize of /dev/xvda1 to 3931652 (4k) blocks.
The filesystem on /dev/xvda1 is now 3931652 blocks long.

~]# df -h
Filesystem Size Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1 **15G** 932M 14G 7% /
tmpfs 498M 0 498M 0% /dev/shm
```

Comment: I was really hoping this would work, but the disk remained the same size afterwards (8G), on CentOS 6 aws image.

Comment: There is no explanation for what is going on here. Not looking for the "blunt" answer but more of a guide line and information.