# increase EC2 EBS volume after cloning - resize2fs not working

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto, amazon-ebs

This is a very similar problem to [EC2 Can't resize volume after increasing size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11014584/ec2-cant-resize-volume-after-increasing-size). However, I cannot resolve this manually using `fdisk` because I'm trying to get the whole process to run automatically.

I'm using a python boto (2.39) script ([snippet](https://gist.github.com/gingerlime/e24a57b6a5a3bf9edf123560599435b9)) which takes a snapshot, registers a new AMI with the same block device mapping, and then creates an instance from it.

It's all working well. The new instance is created with a larger volume size. The new instance is loading ok. The only problem I see is that the partition size is kept at the original size instead of the full size.

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      7.8G  2.4G  5.0G  33% /
```

when I run `resize2fs` it doesn't do anything

```
$ resize2fs /dev/xvda1
resize2fs 1.42.12 (29-Aug-2014)
The filesystem is already 2096128 (4k) blocks long.  Nothing to do!
```

Is there a way to run something **automatically (scripted)** to fix this, or something to do when cloning the image? I'm not using Amazon Linux AMI but rather a debian-based AMI.

Comment: Have you gone into the console and verified that the volume attached to the new instance is actually larger than 8GB? I would do that first to make sure it isn't a problem in the way you are creating the AMI or in the way you are launching the new instance.

Comment: Yes, the attached volume is definitely the right size. I can also follow the manual fdisk process and resize it successfully. But every time I run it - the same thing happens. Looking for a way to automate the fix or avoiding the problem in the first place...

Comment: Ah! Thanks for the pointer, Mark B ! The volume was the right size, but the **snapshot** wasn't updated... Once I updated the snapshot, which had the right size and right partition table, the size was ok... I'm still curious about an automated way to do this fdisk, e.g. if I want to increase the volume size automatically though, but at least it's not a burning issue.

Comment: note - I edited the question to ask about the more general problem (increasing storage size and resizing automatically) rather than the specific problem I was facing.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon Linux will automatically resize the root filesystem to the full size of the volume. This was introduced in **Amazon Linux AMI 2014.03**.

From the [release notes](https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/2014.03-release-notes/):

> **Cloud-Init 0.7.2**
>
> Cloud-Init has been updated to the 0.7 series, adding a number of useful features. One example is `dracut-modules-growroot`, which automatically resizes your root filesystem on boot.

Comment: That's good to know, but I'm not using Amazon Linux AMI (and perhaps users of other AMIs / distros would also be interested finding a way to resize the volume automatically?)