# Not able to resize the AWS EC2 volume

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, filesystems

I created an AWS EC2 Linux instance with 8GB root volume. Then I increased the EBS volume to 9GB and it went to the completed state. It's a small volume, so the resize took a couple of minutes to complete.

Now I try to extend extend the linux file system after resizing the volume using the instructions mentioned [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-expand-volume.html#recognize-expanded-volume-linux). But, I get the below error message. I tried two times, the entire process. But it's all the same.

```
The filesystem is already 2096635 (4k) blocks long.  Nothing to do!
```

Here is the screen shot of the image.

[image]

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 3):

Just **reboot the instance** because it automatically resizes your root filesystem on boot.

I tried it myself. Here is the instance with an 8GB volume:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-15-216 ~]$ lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda    202:0    0   8G  0 disk 
└─xvda1 202:1    0   8G  0 part /

[ec2-user@ip-172-31-15-216 ~]$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs        236M   56K  236M   1% /dev
tmpfs           246M     0  246M   0% /dev/shm
/dev/xvda1      7.8G  985M  6.7G  13% /
```

After modifying the EBS Volume:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-15-216 ~]$ lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda    202:0    0   9G  0 disk 
└─xvda1 202:1    0   8G  0 part /

[ec2-user@ip-172-31-15-216 ~]$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs        236M   56K  236M   1% /dev
tmpfs           246M     0  246M   0% /dev/shm
/dev/xvda1      7.8G  985M  6.7G  13% /
```

After the reboot:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-15-216 ~]$ lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda    202:0    0   9G  0 disk 
└─xvda1 202:1    0   9G  0 part /

[ec2-user@ip-172-31-15-216 ~]$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs        236M   56K  236M   1% /dev
tmpfs           246M     0  246M   0% /dev/shm
/dev/xvda1      8.8G  984M  7.7G  12% /
```

See also: [increase EC2 EBS volume after cloning - resize2fs not working](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36670936/174777)

Answer (score 1):

```
# http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/storage_expand_partition.html
# Before goging to do this, detach and attach the root volume to anothe instance
# Note:
#   1) Before detach the volume, please make a note of device name which going to
#      detch from the machine, why because we should mention same name when attaching back, otherwise data will be lost
#   2)

# Identifying device name which we want to expand
lsblk

# Running parted command on the device
sudo parted /dev/xvdf

# Changing the parted units of measure to sectors.
unit s

# Run the print command to list the partitions on the device
print
# if it shows warning, chose fix

# Delete the partition entry for the partition using the number (1) from the previous step
rm 1 # number 1 will change based the partition we want to delete

# Create a new partition that extends to the end of the volume
mkpart Linux 4096s 100%

# Run the print command again to verify your partition
print

# Check to see that any flags that were present earlier are still
# present for the partition that you expanded. In some cases the boot
# flag may be lost. If a flag was dropped from the partition when it was expanded,
# add the flag with the following command, substituting your partition number and the flag name.
# For example, the following command adds the boot flag to partition 1
set 1 boot on

#Run the quit command to exit parted.
quit

# verfiying the device
sudo e2fsck -f /dev/xvdf1
```

Comment: before proceeding the above steps. you show detach from source machine and attach to another machine. after done the above steps reattach same volume with source machine