# Spark: How to increase drive size in slaves

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-ec2, ec2-ami, spark-ec2

How do I start a cluster with slaves that each have 100GB drive.

```
./spark-ec2 -k xx -i xx.pem -s 1 --hadoop-major-version=yarn --region=us-east-1 \
--zone=us-east-1b  --spark-version=1.6.1 \
--vpc-id=vpc-xx --subnet-id=subnet-xx --ami=ami-yyyyyy \
 launch cluster-test
```

I used an AMI that had the size of 100GB; yet, Spark resized it and started an 8GB drive. How do I increase that limit to 100GB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This solves the issue, yet the question still seeks an answer to avoid having this issue in the first place.*

It turns out that the EBS volume is 100GB but the image on it is only 8 GB. That's why it's only seen as 8GB. To spread the image across the disk, this [blog](http://georgebohnisch.com/resize-gp2-backed-ebs-volume-hvm-instance-aws-ec2/) described in details how to do it. In addition, this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14930504/1019952) is also helpful.