# Resize AWS elastic volume with ext4 filesystem without needing to unmount it

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

So according to https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-ebs-update-new-elastic-volumes-change-everything/

I should be able to increase a volume size 'dynamically' without downtime. However I don't see how this is possible?

I'm able to resize the volume, but I still need to unmount the volume to resize the filesystem parititions. And if this volume is the root volume I would have to take it down in order to unmount it.

What am I missing?

Comment: I agree. This feature just keeps you from having to snapshot and create a new larger volume from the snapshot. It doesn't help with the OS issues involved in resizing a disk volume. The feature hasn't been nearly as helpful as the announcement made it sound.

Comment: What is the benefit of this elastic volume then... If it needs to be unmounted in any case? Grrrr

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have no idea why this answer has so little upvotes but it seems to be the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44354499/1663462

This can be done while running with no downtime (on the root device).

Essentially two commands are required:

```
sudo growpart /dev/xvda 1
sudo resize2fs /dev/xvda1
```

Answer (score 6):

It all depends on what file system you're using on your EBS drive.

I've only done this on Linux, so if you're running something else on your servers I can't help you.

If you're using EXT4 you just call `resize2fs /dev/xvdXY` and it's done, you'll get more space immediately - no remounts or reboots.

For XFS it's `xfs_growfs /dev/xvdXY`.

You should take a snapshot before doing anything of course.

Comment: `sudo resize2fs /dev/xvda1` gives me 
`resize2fs 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)
The filesystem is already 2618595 blocks long.  Nothing to do!`