# error when resizing partition using `growpart` on AWS EBS instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

I have an EC2 instance where I'm attempting to resize the disk on the fly. I've followed the instructions in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42791031/7022062) but when I run `sudo growpart /dev/nvme0n1p1 1`, I get the following error:

`FAILED: failed to get start and end for /dev/nvme0n1p11 in /dev/nvme0n1p1`

What does this mean and how can I resolve it?

---

More info:

Output from `lsblk`:

```
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
nvme0n1     259:0    0   300G  0 disk
└─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   300G  0 part /
```

I can see that EBS volume is in the `in-use (optimizing)` state.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What size does it show in the AWS console?

Comment: @jordanm 600 GiB

Comment: `/dev/nvme0n1` must be used in the argument of `growpart`, not `/dev/nvme0n1p1`.  The second argument `1` is the partition number. The number indicates the index you want to expand.

Comment: @Gre-san thanks! That's a key part I was missing. It didn't work at first but I waited a few hours and eventually it did. Not sure if that was related to the optimization process or what. Thanks again

Comment: Feel free to add it as the answer and I'll mark it as accepted

Comment: @Gre-san Can you make your comment an answer? The AWS docs clearly say what to do, still i managed to ignore it. The problem became clear after i saw your comment.

Answer (score 0):

But for me the solution didn’t work

```
 NAME     MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
```

xvda     202:0    0    8G  0 disk
└─xvda1  202:1    0    8G  0 part /
xvdf     202:80   0  280G  0 disk
├─xvdf1  202:81   0    4G  0 part [SWAP]
├─xvdf2  202:82   0   10G  0 part /data1
├─xvdf3  202:83   0   10G  0 part /data2
├─xvdf4  202:84   0    1K  0 part
├─xvdf5  202:85   0   10G  0 part /applications1
├─xvdf6  202:86   0    4G  0 part /applications2
├─xvdf7  202:87   0    8G  0 part /logsOld
├─xvdf8  202:88   0   50G  0 part /extra
├─xvdf9  202:89   0   20G  0 part /logs
└─xvdf10 202:90   0   64G  0 part /extra/tmp

```
growpart /dev/xvdf 10
```

FAILED: failed to get start and end for /dev/xvdf10 in /dev/xvdf

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the name of the command `growpart` is a bit misleading, because following the [aws instructions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/recognize-expanded-volume-linux.html) you should grow the disk:

```
sudo growpart /dev/nvme0n1 1
```

not the partition `/dev/nvme0n1p1`